# Module exports using two diffrent approches

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module, requirejs

I've node app with the following code( I put sample of the code structure)

This code in the **server.js**  which is the **entry point** to my **nodeModule**

```
function run() {
    app.listen(3001, function () {
        console.log("App is listenting on port 3000");
    })
}

function addPath(args) {
    plug.loadF(args.loadFolder);
};

function preProcess (args) {

    if (_.isEmpty(args)) {
        run();
    }
};

module.exports = preProcess();
module.exports ={
    run: run,
    addPath: addPath
}
```

As you can see the exports twice which in this way I support both option when the app/module is called from **CMD** (call to server.js) and **second** is for calling with using code as dependency under node_modules

1. for `module.exports = preProcess();`
   `module.exports = preProcess();` is if my app/nodeModule is called from external program like java/ buildpack and no args are passed
2. exports `run` and `addPath` which is if my module is installed as node_moudule in user app and you want to call those API by code

My question is there is better way in node to write  those **exports** or if it's ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand the  exports module provided in node.

> The module.exports object is created by the Module system. Sometimes
>   this is not acceptable; many want their module to be an instance of
>   some class. To do this, assign the desired export object to
>   module.exports. Note that assigning the desired object to exports will
>   simply rebind the local exports variable, which is probably not what
>   you want to do.

~ https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports

In simple terms the exports module gives you the functionality of wrapping the entire code in one file such that it can be reused in another file.

Hence obviously one file can only export one object .

In your above code thus you need to encapsulate your methods into one object :

```
var server = {}
server.run = function () {
    app.listen(3001, function () {
        console.log("App is listenting on port 3000");
    })
}

server.addPath = function addPath(args) {
    plug.loadF(args.loadFolder);
};

server.preProcess = function (args) {

    if (_.isEmpty(args)) {
        run();
    }
};

module.exports = server
```

Now on any other page you can simply do :

```
var server = require ("../../path/to/server.js")
server.preProcess() // Call to preprocess function
server.addPath () // Call to addPath function
server.run() // Call to run function
```

Basically I have encapsulated all the methods into a single 'server' object and then exported the object .

Comment: In that case much better use `exports` instead of a new local variable `server`.

Comment: Matter of usage. I like to keep my global objects clutter free .

Comment: @SaleemAhmed - Thanks with your code it work when you call it by code as your example but how it would work without node code invocation? if other program call it like by CMD and call to the server.js and it need to invoke the process like running the server...can you please provide example that answer also the module.exports = preProcess() ?

Comment: @alexmac - what do you mean by using exports ? like I did? if not please provide example , thank you sir

Comment: @SaleemAhmed - I need some logic like IIFE when the module call from external resources ...